# new kernel not showing

Tags: kernel

I have installed Kernel 3.13 (Trusty) to Ubuntu 12.04 and when it asked me if I want to update menu.lst, I selected the default: no.

So now, it boot to Kernel 3.2 instead of 3.13 and there is no 3.13 selection in the grub nor is there any advanced option available.

How do I get Kernel 3.13 as the default?

```
Output for dpkg -l grub*:
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-    pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-    ============================================
ii  grub           0.97-29ubuntu6 GRand Unified Bootloader (Legacy version)
ii  grub-common    1.99-21ubuntu3 GRand Unified Bootloader (common files)
un  grub-coreboot  <none>         (no description available)
un  grub-efi       <none>         (no description available)
un  grub-efi-amd64 <none>         (no description available)
un  grub-efi-ia32  <none>         (no description available)
un  grub-emu       <none>         (no description available)
un  grub-ieee1275  <none>         (no description available)
un  grub-legacy    <none>         (no description available)
un  grub-legacy-do <none>         (no description available)
un  grub-linuxbios <none>         (no description available)
un  grub-pc        <none>         (no description available)
un  grub-yeeloong  <none>         (no description available)
un  grub2          <none>         (no description available)

Output for # dpkg -l linux-image*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-============================================
un  linux-image    <none>         (no description available)
un  linux-image-2. <none>         (no description available)
un  linux-image-2. <none>         (no description available)
un  linux-image-2. <none>         (no description available)
un  linux-image-2. <none>         (no description available)
un  linux-image-3. <none>         (no description available)
ii  linux-image-3. 3.13.0-110.157 Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on     64
ii  linux-image-3. 3.2.0-123.166  Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64     b
ii  linux-image-ge 3.2.0.123.138  Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-ge 3.13.0.110.101 Generic Linux kernel image
un  linux-image-se <none>         (no description available)
```

Comment: It looks like the system is installed with `lilo`, not with grub. That's why you were asked about `menu.lst`. You can install grub normally. What is the device Ubuntu is installed on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grub is not fully installed. You can install `grub` by

```
sudo apt-get install grub-pc
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I see both kernels available in the boot menu. I also see the option to "chainload into GRUB 2" and instruction to upgrade "upgrade-from-grub-legacy". What does chainload mean?

Comment: This is a different question. You had an old version of `grub`. It probably suggests to upgrade to the new one. I do not know the details of this procedure.